# Sorting a list of Strings in Alphabetical order

Tags: java, arrays, string, class

OK, here is my problem. I need to take a array of Strings and sort it alphabetically and then print out the first String: For example, a string of "Georgia, Florida, Alabama", It should print out Alabama. The Strings are not submitted by the user, i have a file with a bunch of states that is inputed as an array.

This is what I have:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class MinString
{
    private static final int SIZE = 10;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
            String[] list = new String[SIZE];
            int numItems;

            numItems = Initialize (list);
            System.out.println(numItems);
    }

    private static int Initialize (String[] list)
    {
      //post : List is initialized with all strings from file.

      String filename, stateInput;
      int i = 0, numItems = 0;
      try  {
            System.out.print("Input File : ");
            Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
            filename = stdin.nextLine();
            stdin = new Scanner(new File(filename));

            while ((stdin.hasNext()) && (i < list.length))
            {
                    stateInput = stdin.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("S = " + stateInput);
                    list[i] = stateInput;
                    i++;
            }
            numItems = i;
      }
      catch (IOException e)  {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
      }
      return numItems;
    }

    // Method FindMin goes here
 private static String FindMin (String[] list, numItems);
 ?????
```

}

I'm not sure how to write this FindMin Method. I need to write FindMin so that it takes as input an array of size numItems of strings and returns to the calling function the minimum string.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
private static String findMin(String[] list) {
    String minState = list[0]; 
    for(int i=1; i<list.length; i++){
        String min=list[i];
        minState=(min!=null&&min.compareTo(minState)<0)?min:minState;
    }
    return minState;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since this feels like a homework I will help you to help yourself:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do it is:

```
return Collections.min(Arrays.asList(list));
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`java.util.Arrays`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) object contains a bunch of static methods for working with arrays. I think [`Arrays.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) would probably help you here. Since Strings implement the [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface with an alphabetic ordering the sorted array should give you the information you need.

Answer (score 0):

just use Arrays.sort(list) and the list will get sorted.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
class Six
{
public static void main(String arg[])
{
String str[]=new String[5];
Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the element of array :");
for(int i=0;i<=4;i++)
{
str[i]=in.next();
}
Arrays.sort(str);
System.out.println("The first element after sorting is:");
System.out.println(str[0]);
}
}
```